# Parallel computing for mediation analyses - foreach and dopar Error not finding assigned object within loop

Tags: r, loops, foreach

I am trying to iterate mediation analyses with a large number of variable combinations (around 700.000 combinations). Thus far I have generated code to produce the exact output that I need and I have tested it on a subset of variable combinations. the code looks (except for the dummy data frames) as follows:

```r
library(mediation)
library(broom)

# Generate random data frames
df1 <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10), b = rnorm(10))
df3 <- data.frame(q = rnorm(10), r = rnorm(10))

#specify column names to generate the desired combinations 
cols1 <- names(df1)
cols2 <- names(df2)
cols3 <- names(df3)

#generate the combinations
combinations <- expand.grid(cols1, cols2, cols3)

# Initialize a data frame to store the results
results <- data.frame(independent = character(),
                      mediator = character(),
                      dependent = character(),
                      ab = numeric(),
                      ac = numeric(),
                      bc = numeric(),
                      p.value = numeric(),
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Loop through each combination and perform a nonparametric causal mediation analysis
for (i in 1:nrow(combinations)) {
  independent <- as.character(combinations[i, 1])
  mediator <- as.character(combinations[i, 2])
  dependent <- as.character(combinations[i, 3])
  
  
  # Combine the independent and mediator variables into a single data frame
  m.data <- data.frame(df1[independent], df2[mediator], df3[dependent])
 
  
  independent <- names(m.data)[1]
  mediator <- names(m.data)[2]
  dependent <- names(m.data)[3]
  
  #  # Fit a model for the independent variable and mediator
   
  model1 <- paste(mediator,dependent,sep = " ~ ") 
  model2 <- paste(dependent,"~", independent,"+",mediator,sep=' ') 
  
  model.M <- lm(model1, data=m.data) 
  model.Y <- lm(model2, data=m.data)
  
  fit <- mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat=dependent, mediator=mediator, 
                 boot=TRUE, sims=500)
  
  tidy_fit <- tidy(fit)
  # Extract the estimates of the total effect (ac) = fit$d0, the direct effect (ab),
  # and the indirect effect (bc) and their p-values
  ab <- tidy_fit$estimate[3]
  ac <- tidy_fit$estimate[1]
  bc <- tidy_fit$estimate[2]
  p.value <-  tidy_fit$p.value[1]
  
  # Add the results to the data frame
  results <- rbind(results, data.frame(independent = independent,
                                       mediator = mediator,
                                       dependent = dependent,
                                       ab = ab,
                                       ac = ac,
                                       bc = bc,
                                       p.value = p.value,
                                       stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}

print(results)
```

The code is basically optimal. The  issue is that given the number of combinations, this runs forever. So I am trying to parallelize the process but have basically zero knowledge on this and my attempts thus far have failed. I have tried the following:

```r
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
cores <- 4

# Initialize a cluster
cl <- makeCluster(cores)


# Register the cluster
registerDoParallel(cl)
results <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(combinations), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
  independent <- as.character(combinations[i, 1])
  mediator <- as.character(combinations[i, 2])
  dependent <- as.character(combinations[i, 3])
  
  independent_col <- df1[, independent]
  mediator_col <- df2[, mediator]
  dependent_col <- df3[, dependent]
  
  # Combine the independent and mediator variables into a single data frame
  m.data <- data.frame(df1[independent], df2[mediator], df3[dependent])
  # colnames(m.data) <- c("independent", "mediator", "dependent")
  
  independent <- names(m.data)[1]
  mediator <- names(m.data)[2]
  dependent <- names(m.data)[3]
  
  model1 <- paste(mediator,dependent,sep = " ~ ") 
  model2 <- paste(dependent,"~", independent,"+",mediator,sep=' ') 
  
  model.M <- lm(model1, data=m.data) 
  model.Y <- lm(model2, data=m.data)
  
  fit <- mediation::mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat = dependent, mediator = mediator,
                            boot = TRUE, sims = 500)
  
  tidy_fit <- tidy(fit)
  # Extract the estimates of the total effect (ac) = fit$d0, the direct effect (ab),
  # and the indirect effect (bc) and their p-values
  ab <- tidy_fit$estimate[3] #ADE
  ac <- tidy_fit$estimate[1] #ACME
  bc <- tidy_fit$estimate[2] #TOTAL EFFECT
  p.value <-  tidy_fit$p.value[1]
  
  # Add the results to the data frame
  data.frame(independent = independent,
             mediator = mediator,
             dependent = dependent,
             ab = ab,
             ac = ac,
             bc = bc,
             p.value = p.value,
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

this throws an error: Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'model1' not found". if I define i = 1 and run the code that is in the loop as a single iteration with the defined i, the code works fine, so it seems to me that the variable model1 is not accessible within the worker function. anyone has any idea how to go about solving this? any other suggestion for parallelization (bbapply or splitting in chunks...) is welcome (I am equally unfamiliar with these options :D). Thanks!

technical info:  MacOS Big Sur, R Version 4.1.1

Comment: What does "forever" mean? >10 minutes, >1 hour, >1 day ... ???

Comment: if I test this with 10 rows of my combinations, it takes a bit less than a minute. it has been running at a fairly uniform rate for the last 10 h, so a naive extrapolation gets me > 1000 h :S

Answer (score 1):

ok, so I tried something else and this seems to work. Importantly, the small addition from Ben makes all the difference.

```
#after initialising the results dataframe as per the above 
# set the number of cores to use
cores <- 20

# Initialize a cluster
cl <- makeCluster(cores)

# Register the cluster
registerDoParallel(cl)

# define a custom function to perform mediation analysis on each combination of variables

mediation_analysis <-
function(i) {
  independent <- as.character(combinations[i, 1])
  mediator <- as.character(combinations[i, 2])
  dependent <- as.character(combinations[i, 3])
  
  independent_col <- df1[, independent]
  mediator_col <- df2[, mediator]
  dependent_col <- df3[, dependent]
  
  # Combine the independent and mediator variables into a single data frame
  m.data <- data.frame(df1[independent], df2[mediator], df3[dependent])
  
  independent <- names(m.data)[1]
  mediator <- names(m.data)[2]
  dependent <- names(m.data)[3]
  model1 <- paste(mediator,dependent,sep = " ~ ") 
  model2 <- paste(dependent,"~", 
  independent,"+",mediator,sep=' ') 
  model.M <- do.call(lm, list(model1, data=m.data))
  model.Y <- do.call(lm, list(model2, data=m.data))
  fit <- mediation::mediate(model.M, model.Y, treat = 
  dependent, mediator = mediator,
                 boot = TRUE, sims = 500)
  
  tidy_fit <-broom::tidy(fit)
  # Extract the estimates of the total effect (ac) = fit$d0, the direct effect (ab),
  # and the indirect effect (bc) and their p-values
  ab <- tidy_fit$estimate[3] #ADE
  ac <- tidy_fit$estimate[1] #ACME
  bc <- tidy_fit$estimate[2] #TOTAL EFFECT
  p.value <-  tidy_fit$p.value[1] #p-value
  
  # Add the results to the data frame
  data.frame(independent = independent,
             mediator = mediator,
             dependent = dependent,
             ab = ab,
             ac = ac,
             bc = bc,
             p.value = p.value,
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

# perform mediation analysis on each combination of variables using foreach
results <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(combinations), .combine = rbind) %dopar% {
  mediation_analysis(i)
}

# stop the cluster
stopCluster(cl)

# view the results
print(results)
```

I ran this in an interactive session on a compute server and the elapsed time is 7.839 for the same example given above. So it's a decent improvement. Thanks for any other helpful input.

Answer (score 0):

I messed around with this for a while, but it's hard, due to something about the way that `mediate` works with environments. You can get around the first set of errors by replacing your model fits in the loop payload with:

```r
model.M <- do.call(lm, list(model1, data=m.data))
model.Y <- do.call(lm, list(model2, data=m.data))
```

Setting `.errorhandling = "pass"` gets you a *little* bit more information about what's going wrong, but not much: it returns

> <simpleError in if (xhat == 0) out <- 1 else {    out <- 2 * min(sum(x > 0), sum(x < 0))/length(x)}: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed>

[Searching for "xhat" in the mediation package source code](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Akosukeimai%2Fmediation%20xhat&type=code) tells us that this is happening in `mediation:::pval`, but I can't get much farther than that (it doesn't really help that the `mediate.R` file is 2000 lines of R code ...)

**A possible workaround** (??): your original, non-parallelized R code is doing something that is known to be very slow, i.e. growing a data frame one row at a time (see chapter 2 of https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). If your loop is instead structured as:

```r
res_list <- list()
for (i in ...) {
   ... 
   res_list[[i]] <- data.frame(...)
}
results <- do.call("rbind", res_list)
```

you may find that your code goes **much** faster.  I would try running your loop on (say) the first 100, 200, 400 ... rows of your 'combinations' data frame and see how it scales ...

(Unasked-for statistical comment: although I admit I don't know any of the details, I have to admit that I am suspicious of any analysis that looks at possible effects of mediation over 700,000 predictor combinations ...)

Comment: thanks for the reply Ben, I admit I thought this might be much more straightforward. I tested your suggestion. basically with my non-parallelized, elapsed time for 8 mediations is 40.582, while it's 40.593 with the suggested modification. the system time is shorter but all in all, no real benefit here. the nonparametric boostraps are the bottleneck, hence the need to parallelize (700.000 mediation tests, not predictor combos). I didn't want to cherry-pick, hence I was hoping the results would help me weed out, but might not have a workaround that. Thanks anyways

Comment: There are ways to brute-force this; I could show you how to do that.  How many cores do you expect to have to do the problem?  If every mediation takes 5 seconds to compute, then you have 972 hours of computation to do.  Are you going to be able to find 100 cores so you can get through this in only 10 hours ... ?  What OS are you on?

Comment: I am definitely going to weed out a bunch of variables and will try implementing the function in combo with dopar (see added answer) on the uppmax computing cluster. I just have to figure out how to script this outside an interactive session and submit it decently :D